# Problem in normed spaces

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Some help with the following would be great.

> Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a normed space.
>
> Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ and $(y_{n})_{n}$ be Cauchy sequences in $(X, D)$. Say also that $s_{n} = ||x_{n} + y_{n}||$.
>
> Prove that $s_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$.
>
> Use the following:
>
> $\large{|} \hspace{2pt} \normalsize||x-y||-||u-v|| \hspace{2pt}\large{|} \normalsize \le  ||x-u|| + ||y-v||$

So I'm guessing we need to use the fact that $(x_{n})_{n}$ and $(y_{n})_{n}$ are Cauchy, then need to get it into the form of the hint.

But how?

Comment: Come on, at least try to follow your nose and write down what you need to prove: the definition of $s_n$ being Cauchy. There is really only one thing to do.

Comment: To further expand on the previous comment: This kind of exercise is essentially just a matter of applying the definition. "Let $\varepsilon > 0$, then $|s_n-s_m| = \dotsb \leq \dotsb = \lVert x_n - x_m\rVert + \lVert y_n - y_m\rVert$. Since $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy there exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $[\ldots]$, so for $n,m \geq N$ we have $|s_n - s_m| < \varepsilon$, i.e. $(s_n)$ is Cauchy $\quad\blacksquare$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$|s_n-s_m|=\left|\|x_n-(-y_n)\|-\|x_m-(-y_m)\|\right|\leq \|x_n-x_m\|+\|-y_n+y_m\|$$
and so since $(x_n),(y_n)$ are Cauchy, for any $\epsilon>0$ we have some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $$n,m\geq N\implies \|x_n-x_m\|<\epsilon/2$$
and similarly we have some $N'\in\mathbb N$ such that such that 
$$n,m\geq N'\implies \|y_n-y_m\|<\epsilon/2$$
so 
$$n,m\geq \max\{N,N'\}\implies |s_n-s_m|\leq \|x_n-x_m\|+\|-y_n+y_m\|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$$
thus $(s_n)$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\begin{align*}
|s_n-s_m|&=|\,\|x_n+y_n\|-\|x_m+y_m\|\,|\\
&=|\,\|x_n-(-y_n)\|-\|x_m-(-y_m)\|\,|
\end{align*}$$